# SQL code won't run when CASE function is inserted?

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, case

I am trying to fit a CASE function into some SQL code and can't get it to run. Everything has worked perfectly up until the CASE function, and whenever that is inserted, I get a debug error. I was assisted in making this program so I'm hoping it's just a simple error that I'm ignorant of. This is pulling select content from 2 large excel tables based on meeting the criteria. The CASE function is determining whether a value is > or < 12000 and pumping out content based on which content matches that criteria. THANKS!!

See code below:

```
Dim fPath As String
    Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sPath As String, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, SQL As String
    
    fPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName 'workbook must be saved somewhere...
    
    'connect to the workbook on disk
    oConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" & _
               "DBQ=" & fPath & ";"
       
    'select some records which match between lists (zipccode and subdivision)
    '   and with the entered criteria (price, SQFT)
    SQL = " select n.*, o.* from  [OldList$] o, [NewList$] n " & _
          " where n.zipcode = o.zipcode and left(n.Subdivision, 6) = left(o.Subdivision, 6)" & _
          " and (n.listprice - o.listprice) between " & shtCriteria.Range("C4").Value & " and " & shtCriteria.Range("D4").Value & _
          " and (n.sqft - o.sqft) between " & shtCriteria.Range("C6").Value & " and " & shtCriteria.Range("D6").Value & _
          " and CASE " & _
          "         WHEN n.lot > 12000 " & _
          "             THEN o.lot between n.lot + n.lot* " & shtCriteria.Range("C8").Value & " and n.lot + n.lot* " & shtCriteria.Range("D8").Value & " " & _
          "         ELSE (n.lot - o.lot) between " & shtCriteria.Range("C9").Value & " and " & shtCriteria.Range("D9").Value & _
          "     END "
        

            
    Set oRS = oConn.Execute(SQL) 'run the query
```

Comment: Case is not a function, it's an *expression*.  your case expression is malformed, you need to review the documentation for your specific RDBMS. Ideally edit your question to include the *actual* SQL statement, not the code that dynamically constructs it. And see [Bad habbits to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Use parentheses and AND/OR logical operators instead?

Comment: Also consider using parameters (and `?` placeholders in the SQL) instead of concatenating unvalidated inputs (what if a cell contains an unexpected value, an error, or ..some SQL statements?); you'd be invoking the `Execute` method of an `ADODB.Command` instance instead of directly off the connection.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll give it a try. Still trying to learn the basics here. Appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` returns different results of the same type depending on conditions. It’s not for executing alternate code blocks as you have attempted.

Remove `CASE` and use `OR` and `AND`.

You have used it like this:

```
WHERE …
AND CASE
      WHEN n.lot > 12000
        THEN <condition 1>
      ELSE <condition 2>
    END
```

Change it to:

```
WHERE …
AND (
    (n.lot > 12000 AND <condition 1>)
    OR
    (n.lot <= 12000 AND <condition 2>)
)
```